# Converse of Borel Cantelli from Pollard

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I've started working through Pollard's a User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability, and I've run into some issues solving the following problem:

Let $A_1, A_2, ...$ be events defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_i}$. We assume that $\mu_n = \mathbb{E}X_n \to \infty$, and $\|X_n / \mu_n\|_2 \to 1$. Note: I'm not sure why Pollard uses the 2-norm here, but I don't think that matters much.

I've established (in a previous exercise) that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$
\mathbb{1}_{X_n = 0} \leq \frac{(k-X_n)(k+1-X_n)}{k(k+1)}
$$

The exercise is to show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \geq 1$ almost surely. My original idea for proving this was to note that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{A_i} < 1$ iff $X_n = 0$ for all $n$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. My intuition is that $X_n$ behaves roughly like its expectation, which limits to infinity, so $X_n$ will be non-zero almost surely --- but I'm having trouble converting that intuition to a proper proof. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! As a side note, Pollard uses slightly odd notation, so this is not how the exercise appears in the book itself.

Comment: The answer below certainly solves the question, but if you want to use the previous exercise, note that if we take the expectation of your previous exercise, we get $P(X_n=0)\leq \frac{k(k+1)-X_n(2k+1)-X_n^2}{k(k+1)}$. If we try to make this small by picking a suitable value of $k$, we can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n = 0)=0.$ Then, use that $X_{n+1} \geq X_n$ and Borel Cantelli.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble trying to make the RHS small by picking $k$ (which I think is most of where my issue with this problem comes from). Could you clarify how I might go about doing that?

Comment: If you pick $k$ close to $\mu_n$, (if this holds for noninteger $k$ it's even better) you should see that the limit roughly simplifies to $(1-E(X_n^2/\mu_n^2))/(\mu_n+1).$

Comment: Oh of course, that makes so much sense -- thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just to follow up on this. Upon reflection I realized that my original usage of Borel-Cantelli to show that P(X = 0) = 0 (where $X$ is just the limit of the $X_n$'s) doesn't quite work. Would you be willing to give a hint about how to apply it?

Comment: Since $X_{n+1} \geq X_n$, pick a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X_{n_k} = 0) < \infty.$ This shows almost surely that $X_{n_k} = 0$ for finitely many $n_k$. Note that if $X_{n_k} = 0$, for all $m \leq n_k$, $X_m \leq X_{n_k} = 0$ so we have shown that almost surely, $X_n = 0$ for finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^\infty I(A_i)$ and let $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^nI(A_i)$ where $I$ is the indicator function. Then note that
$$
P(X>0)\geq P(X_n\gt 0)\geq \frac{(EX_n)^2}{EX_n^2}\tag{0}
$$
since $(X_n > 0)\subset (X>0)$ and we used the in the final inequality we used the  [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).

By assumption $EX_n^2/(EX_n)^2\to 1$. Hence letting $n\to\infty$ in $(0)$, $P(X>0) =1$ as desired.

Comment: I'll be sure to remember that inequality -- thanks!